# How to decrease the computation time of this code?

Tags: matlab, performance, time, cell

I am working on computing some features of an image data set and saving the features for later use. Below is the code:

```
tic
l = 9907 % size of image data set
% pre-allocating space for variables in the for loop
Icolor = cell(1,l);
Iwave = cell(1,l);
IglrlFeatures = cell(1,l);
for i = 1:l % l = size of image data set = 9907
    IDB{1,i} = imread(strcat(path,strcat(num2str(i),'.jpg')));
    Icolor{1,i} = colorMoments(IDB{1,i}); % 6-features in each cell
    Iwave{1,i} = waveletTransform(IDB{1,i}); % 8-features in each cell
    IglrlFeatures{1,i}  = textureFeatures(IDB{1,i}); % 44-features in each cell
    ICW{1,i} = [Icolor{1,i} Iwave{1,i} IglrlFeatures{1,i}];
end
toc
```

**Here the computation time for each function on single image is:**

colorMoments(single_image) = Elapsed time is 0.009689 seconds.

waveletTransform(single_image) = Elapsed time is 0.018069 seconds.

textureFeatures(single_image) = Elapsed time is 0.022902 seconds.

**l = data set size = 9907 images**

**Computational times for different data set sizes (l):**

l = 10; Elapsed time is 0.402629 seconds.

l = 100; Elapsed time is 2.233971 seconds.

l = 1000; Elapsed time is 21.178395 seconds.

l = 2000; Elapsed time is 44.510071 seconds.

l = 5000; Elapsed time is 111.393866 seconds.

l = 9907; Elapsed time is 238.924998 seconds. approximately (~4 mins)

I want to decrease this computational time, any suggestions?

Thanks,

Gopi

Comment: Your title says you want to increase the time and your question says you want to decrease the time. Which is it?

Comment: I am sorry i meant decrease the compuatation time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measured times seem to indicate computational complexity of order O(n). I doubt that the order can be reduced further for this type of problem. So, I believe that, at best, we can only hope for a linear increase in performance.

One thing you should look into is whether the code is using multiple processor cores. If not, try restructuring the `for`-loop to be able to use [`parfor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfor.html) instead.

Comment: I used both parfor and parallel pool and computation improved significantly.. For comparision on dataset of 9907 images it increased from   238 secs to 32 secs..I aloso changed the variable name from "path" to something else as someone suggested .. it significantly improved performace as well